# placehold.it print non-English words

Tags: javascript, html, css, placeholder

The link below will print "hello world" on a place holder image provided by http://placehold.it
http://placehold.it/200&text=hello+world

Is it possible to print non-English words on it, say Chinese or Japanese? If it cannot, are there any service available to do so?

Comment: Which programming language you are using for printing this?

Comment: I want to embed the place holders into html, I am using http://placehold.it/200&text=<?php print($someStr) ?>.

Comment: You can use UTF-8 Encoding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create images printed non-English words. See [here](http://placehold.jp/en.html).

[Here](http://placehold.jp/30/3d4070/ffffff/300x200.png?text=%C3%84%20%C3%9C%20%C3%96%20%C3%A4%20%C3%BC%20%C3%B6%20%C3%9F) is such a sample.

Answer (score 0):

The place holder images can be easily emulated by a div with the same size (set in .css). I then can add any text on it.